# "Create New Account" button Thunderbird (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) not working

Tags: 18.04, email, thunderbird

I just moved to Ubuntu and am trying to set up a second email account (Gmail).

After setting up successfully the first (iCloud), when I try to repeat the procedure and click on "Skip this and use my existing account" nothing pops up.

Do you have an alternative procedure for that? I tried to click on "File" as well, but apparently there is no "New" option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click `Edit`, in the dropdown-menu choose `Account Settings`. In the Account-Settings-window click `Account Actions` and choose the appropriate action.